# Join 3 Tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables:

```
notes: id, business_id, note

businesses: id, title, description

businessimages : id, business_id, image
```

I want to get `notes.id, businesses.id, businesses.title, businesses.description, businessimages.image`

How could I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = DB::table('businesses')
            ->join('notes', 'notes.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
            ->join('businessimages', 'businessimages.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
            ->select('businesses.*', 'notes.note', 'businessimages.image')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother hope it works

```
$data = DB::table('notes)
            ->select(
                'notes.id',
                'businesses.id AS businesses_id',
                'businesses.title',
                'businesses.description',
                'businessesimages.image'
            )
            ->join('businesses', 'businesses.id', '=', 'notes.businesses_id')
            ->join('businessesimages', 'businessesimages.businesses_id', '=', 'notes.businesses_id')
            ->get();
```

Explore more:
[Query Builder|**Joining Table**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

how to use join

```
$results = DB::table('businesses')
            ->select('notes.id as notes_id', 'businesses.id as business_id','businesses.title', 'businesses.description', 'businessimages.image' )
            ->join('notes', 'notes.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
            ->join('businessimages ', 'businessimages.business_id', '=', 'businesses.id')
            ->get();
```