# Laravel Tables Join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables:

```
notes: id, business_id, note

businesses: id, title, description

businessimages : id, business_id, image
```

I get my customers notes with this:

```
$customer = Auth::guard('customer-api')->user();

$notes = Note::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->with('business:id')- 
>orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Now I want to get notes.id, businesses.id, businesses.title, businesses.description, `businessimages.image` for each notes and show all of them in one json array

How could I do?

Comment: Did you do some research or write some come and it did not work?

Comment: Looks like you haven't given it a try at all. There is no `customer_id` column in `notes` table mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join 3 Tables in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920566/join-3-tables-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note model;

```
public function business() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Business', 'business_id', 'id');
}
```

Business mode;

```
public function businessImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\BusinessImage', 'business_id', 'id');
}
```

Your controller;

```
$notes = Note::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->with('business.businessImage')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
Note::where('customer_id',$customer->id)
  ->join('businesses', 'businesses.id', '=', 'notes.buisness_id')
  ->join('businessimages', 'businesses.id', '=', 'businessimages.buisness_id')
  ->select(notes.id, businesses.id, businesses.title, businesses.description,businessimages.image)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

This is a great way to organize a model(or a collection of models as well).

App\Note

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
    }
}
```

App\Business

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
    public function note()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Note');
    }

    public function businessImage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\BusinessImage');
    }
}
```

App\BusinessImage

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BusinessImage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'businessimages';

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Business');
    }
}
```

App\Http\Resources\Note

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

class Note
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'noteId' => $this->resource->id,
            'businessId' => $this->resource->business->id,
            'businessTitle' => $this->resource->business->title,
            'businessDescription' => $this->resource->business->description,
            'businessImage' => $this->resource->business->businessImage->image
        ];
    }
}
```

Somewhere in a controller

```
use App\Http\Resources\Note as NoteResource;

    public function foo()
    {
        $customer = Auth::guard('customer-api')->user();
        $notes = Note::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->with(['business','business.businessImage'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return NoteResource::collection($notes);
    }
```